# how to mock test Kotlin Spring boot 2 application

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

I am trying to test a spring boot application written completely in kotlin.

I am trying to test the Service layer mocking the repository object. Code is as bellow

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class TaskServiceTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var taskRepository: TaskRepository
    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var taskService: TaskService

    @Test
    fun createNewTaskFailTest() {
        val taskRequest = TaskRequest("fullName", "94123456789", "", "")
        val newTask = Task(
                id = null,
                status = PENDING)
        val savedTask = newTask.copy(id = 1L)
        given(taskRepository.save(newTask)).willReturn(savedTask)
        val createdTask = taskService.createTask(taskRequest)
        Assert.assertEquals(createdTask.status, PENDING)
    }
}
```

when I run this code I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: savedTask must not be null

    at com.hsenid.servicestatusinquiry.service.TaskService.createTask(TaskService.kt:46)
    at com.hsenid.servicestatusinquiry.service.TaskServiceTest.createNewTaskFailTest(TaskServiceTest.kt:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

[MockitoHint] TaskServiceTest.createNewTaskFailTest (see javadoc for MockitoHint):
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at com.hsenid.servicestatusinquiry.service.TaskServiceTest.createNewTaskFailTest(TaskServiceTest.kt:40)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at com.hsenid.servicestatusinquiry.service.TaskService.createTask(TaskService.kt:45)
```

create task is working fine when I call it from controller with http call

bellow is create task code sample

```
    fun createTask(taskRequest: TaskRequest): Task {
        val newTask = Task(
                id = null,
                status = PENDING)
        val savedTask = repository.save(newTask)
        return savedTask
    }
```

how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin expert, but in Java, the `newTask` you create in the `createTask` function wouldn't be the same as the `newTask` you are referring to in setting up the mock, as they are two separate instances. I haven't tested it, but I _think_ that if you use Mockito's [`eq` matcher](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html) where you define the mock, it should work, so: `given(taskRepository.save(eq(newTask))).willReturn(savedTask)`. Failing that either `refEq` or `any(Task.class)` might be helpful to try.

Comment: any(Task.class) it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me

```
given(taskRepository.save(any(Task.class))).willReturn(savedTask)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

First I annotate my class with:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class TaskServiceTest
```

Then:

```
private fun <T> anyObject(): T {
    Mockito.anyObject<T>()
    return uninitialized()
}

Mockito.`when`<Any>(taskRepository.save(anyObject()))
            .thenReturn(validTask())
```

Worked for me.